# PSD file not resizing properly

Tags: c#, image-resizing, imageresizer

I am trying to bulk resize PSD images into jpg using http://imageresizing.net/

The PSD images are not getting converted properly.

[image]

Help

I have added reference to psdcomposer & freeImage
and using it.

[image]

```
ImageResizer.Configuration.Config c = new ImageResizer.Configuration.Config();
//PsdReader psReader = new PsdReader();
ImageResizer.Plugins.PsdComposer.PsdComposerPlugin composer = new ImageResizer.Plugins.PsdComposer.PsdComposerPlugin();
//ImageResizer.Plugins.Wic.InteropServices.ComTypes.ExifColorSpace.sRGB
//ImageResizer.Plugins.Wic.InteropServices.MemoryIStream wic = new ImageResizer.Plugins.Wic.InteropServices.MemoryIStream(); 
ImageResizer.Plugins.FreeImageDecoder.FreeImageDecoderPlugin freeImage = new ImageResizer.Plugins.FreeImageDecoder.FreeImageDecoderPlugin();

//psReader.Install(c);
composer.Install(c);
//freeImage.Install(c);
```

I am passing following parameters:
`scale=both&mode=max&ignoreicc=false&dpi=72&width=1280&height=1280`

Help

Comment: You think mabey contacting the author of the ImageResizer component might be a better option rather than people that have not coded it.

Comment: Sample PSD which is not getting converted: https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B5s7cXZgfIAoTTVYaDdLR0VSV28/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0):

#### You need to specify which pipeline should handle the image. FreeImage and PsdComposer are mutually exclusive.

FreeImage renders the embedded bitmap from the .PSD file, while PsdComposer will re-render all layers in the PSD (a much more expensive and less accurate, but more flexible approach).

#### Use `decoder=freeimage` to use the pre-rendered version of the PSD.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I installed both plugins & tried both the parameters one by one, both did not work, I got bad image output.   `decoder=psdcomposer&scale=both&mode=max&quality=100&format=jpg&ignoreicc=false&dpi=72&width=240&height=240`

Comment: The sample PSD file uses a clipping mask, which PsdComposer does not support. Use freeimage instead; it doesn't make sense to use PsdComposer when you don't need to programmatically edit the PSD file prior to rendering.